# IoC container that can register everything (non generic) automatically without configuration (assembly to assembly)

Tags: castle-windsor, unity-container, structuremap, ninject, autofac

the idea is that I have a Core project with lots of interfaces, also Data and Service project with implementations (everything 1-to-1), e.g.:

```
Core { IFooRepo, IBarRepo, IFooService, IBarService}
Data {FooRepo: IFooRepo, BarRepo : IBarRepo}
Service {FooService : IFooService, BarService : IBarService}
```

so I would like something like

```
register(Core, Data);
register(Core, Service);
```

there are lots of IoC containers and I don't know which one of them can do this, or is closer to this solution, anybody knows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor lets you easily register classes as interfaces they expose, either all of them or, selectively. ([see the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Selecting_service_for_the_component_16)).

It does not have OOTB support for your scenario (filtering implemented interfaces to only include those from specific assembly) but (as for everything in Windsor) there's a hook you can use to easily have that.

```
container.Register(
   AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<SomeClass>()
      WithService.Select((type, @base) =>
         type.GetAllInterfaces()
             .Where(i => i.Assembly == yourInterfacesAssembly)))
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about auto-registration. Many IoC containers support this.

StructureMap
http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm

Castle Windsor (see bottom of 2nd page of the article)
http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0906051

Autofac
http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning

Ninject
Looks like you can do it via Kernel.Scan(), though I couldn't find docs. (Server was unavailable.)
[How to use Ninject Conventions extension without referencing Assembly (or Types within it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019585/how-to-use-ninject-conventions-extension-without-referencing-assembly-or-types-w)

Last I looked, Unity did not support auto-registration, though that may have changed with a recent release.

UPDATE: Thanks to Mauricio for noticing that I incorrectly identified the desired feature as auto-wiring. Corrected and updated the links.

Comment: This is not about auto-wiring. Auto-wiring is about automatically setting up dependencies, not automatically registering stuff in batch based on assembly scanning and conventions which is what the OP is asking about. Of course, registering by scanning assemblies pretty much requires auto-wiring, but they're different things.

Comment: @Mauricio - Now that I think about it, you're right. What the OP is talking about is auto-registration, though the two are often used hand-in-hand. Thanks for catching my error.

Answer (score 3):

In Autofac the simplest way to achieve this is:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

var data = typeof(BarRepo).Assembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(data).AsImplementedInterfaces();

var service = typeof(BarService).Assembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(service).AsImplementedInterfactes();

var container = builder.Build();
```

Now this will not be selective about the service interfaces being from the Core assembly. If this really matters (it probably shouldn't) then vary the above registrations along these lines:

```
var core = typeof(IBarRepo).Assembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(data)
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
         .Where(i => i.Assembly == core)
         .Select(i => new TypedService(i)));
```

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: As of the latest commit, the Select(i => new TypedService(i)) clause is no longer needed.