# Ninject Dynamically Loading a Repository from an Assembly

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, ninject-2

I'm using:

- EF 4.1
- MVC 3
- Ninject
- Ninject.Extensions.Conventions
- Ninject.Web.Mvc

The app uses the repository pattern.
My Repositories can be injected like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ICategoryRepository>().To<CategoryRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

and it all works fine :-)

But i've neen attempting to go further with dynamically injecting from an asssembly like this in my global.asax.cs

```
private static void LoadFromAssemblies(IKernel kernel)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(
      Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) +
      @"\Extensions");
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(uri.LocalPath);

    var scanner = new AssemblyScanner();

    scanner.FromAssembliesInPath(directoryInfo.FullName);
    scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
    kernel.Scan(scanner);

    //var foo = kernel.Get<ICategoryRepository>();
}
```

At run time the repository does get injected, but for some reason the entity never gets saved - perhaps because the repository can't tell if there are changes? or the unit of work is not maintained across the request?

My question is: How do i implement a "InRequestScope" when dynamically loading from assemblies? Do i have to somehow inject the kernel?

Comment: ok, so i found this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019585/how-to-use-ninject-conventions-extension-without-referencing-assembly-or-types-w
and so this approached answers and solves my problem.

  kernel.Scan(a =>
            {
                a.FromAssembliesInPath(directoryInfo.FullName);
                a.AutoLoadModules();
                a.BindWithDefaultConventions();
                a.**InRequestScope**();
            });

Answer (score 2):

This approach (marked `***`) answers and solves the problem (copied from @John Barrett's comment):

```
kernel.Scan(a =>
  {
    a.FromAssembliesInPath(directoryInfo.FullName);
    a.AutoLoadModules();
    a.BindWithDefaultConventions();
    a.InRequestScope();  // <-- ***
  });
```